# Can magnons or phonons exist at zero temperature?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, symmetry-breaking, quasiparticles

Can in principle, magnons or phonons exist at zero temperature? If not, why? If yes, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Phonon modes are the eigenmodes of the dynamical matrix. The solutions exists independent of temperature. But at zero temperature none of these modes are occupied. Only the zero point energy remains. In that sense: no, there are no phonons at 0K.